# Find the coordinates of a Bounding Box when it is rotated by an angle and zoomed a bit.

Tags: trigonometry

I have come across a problem where I need to find the coordinates of a Bounding Box when image is rotated by angles of ±45° and ±22.5°, and zoomed a bit.

I have come across a formula which finds the coordinates after rotation of rectangle from the center.

$x_2 = x_0+(x-x_0)*\cos(\theta)+(y-y_0)*\sin(\theta)$.

$y_2 = y_0-(x-x_0)*\sin(\theta)+(y-y_0)*\cos(\theta)$.

where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the center around which you are rotating.
But this formula only calculate coordinates for rectangles rotated along the center.

The main issue is that the image gets zoomed when it is rotated in order to fit the dimensions of the original image(800x480 px), as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ksr.png). The images after rotation by 45 degrees get zoomed by 88.59%.

I am trying to create a formula which can be used to calculate the new coordinates of rotated and zoomed bounding box.

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the question. PS: This is my first StackExchange question.

Comment: Great, Ashwij!  Thanks!